# Making Agda reduce an expression in a goal type

Tags: agda, dependent-type, theorem-proving

Using `ℕ` and `_≟_` from [the standard library](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Nat/Base.agda), I have

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Nullary

foo : ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ
foo x y with x ≟ y
foo x .x | yes refl = x
foo x y  | no contra = y

data Bar : ℕ -> Set where
  bar : (x : ℕ) -> Bar (foo x x)
```

I want to implement

```
mkBar : (x : ℕ) -> Bar x
mkBar x = bar x
```

Agda complains,

```
Type mismatch:
expected: x
  actual: foo x x | x ≟ x
when checking that the expression bar x
has type Bar x
```

This makes sense to me: Agda doesn't know *a priori* that `x ≟ x` always evaluates to `yes refl`, so it's not going to evaluate `foo x x` until it knows a bit more about `x`.

So I tried rewriting the goal to force `x ≟ x` to resolve to `yes refl`,

```
eq-refl : forall x -> (x ≟ x) ≡ yes refl
eq-refl x with x ≟ x
eq-refl x | yes refl = refl
eq-refl x | no contra = ⊥-elim (contra refl)

mkBar : (x : ℕ) -> Bar x
mkBar x rewrite eq-refl x = bar x
```

but to no avail. Same error message. I also tried rewriting by `foo x x ≡ x`:

```
foo-eq : forall x -> foo x x ≡ x
foo-eq x rewrite eq-refl x = refl

mkBar : (x : ℕ) -> Bar x
mkBar x rewrite foo-eq x = bar x
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12500950/7951906) suggests pattern matching on `x ≟ x` on the left hand side of `mkBar`, but it also seems to have no effect:

```
mkBar : (x : ℕ) -> Bar x
mkBar x with x ≟ x
mkBar x | yes refl = bar x
mkBar x | no contra = ⊥-elim (contra refl)
```

I must be missing a trick here. How do I get rid of the `|` in the goal type and make `foo x x` reduce to `x`? (I'd prefer not to examine `x` directly in the LHS of `mkBar`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there: the important thing to notice is that `rewrite` takes an `x ≡ y` and replaces `x` by `y` in the goal. `foo-eq x` has type `foo x x ≡ x` but there is no `foo x x` to replace in the goal!

What you need to do is rewrite by `sym (foo-eq x)` like so:

```
mkBar : (x : ℕ) → Bar x
mkBar x rewrite sym (foo-eq x) = bar x
```

`Bar x` then becomes `Bar (foo x x)` meaning you can apply your constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! I think I finally understand how `rewrite` works now (I hadn't twigged that it puts the _left-hand side_ of `_≡_` into the generated `with` clause), so thanks for that. However, it would appear that I've done a bad job of asking the question, because your answer doesn't seem to work in my actual code. I thought I had a minimal repro but I don't! Would you mind taking a very quick look at [this paste](http://lpaste.net/355574) to see if there's something obvious I've missed?

Comment: It's a similar situation: the expression you're targetting is not part of the goal yet (it only shows up in a subgoal after you've introduced a lot of constructors). You can either use `subst` in that location to fix `sub x b`'s type or bring `sub x b` as an expression into the context using a `with`-abstraction and then following that with a rewrite [like so](http://lpaste.net/355596)

Comment: Got it! That makes perfect sense. Seems that I need to improve my theorem proving instincts :) Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with the head constructors question! ;)